# How to create a custom page in wordpress admin, in which no default content must be loaded

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Currently i am loading my custom page of WP-Plugin by using hook i.e

```
add_action('admin_init','myfunction')
function myfunction(){
    include("login.php");
    return exit;
}
```

i am just checking the session value and include the login.php file and return exit.
when i return exit it doesn't load default content of wordpress. Now if i want to enqueue a script in my login page i.e "login.php" with wp_enqueue_script() it doesn't work. Because, it didn't load wordpress default functions as i returned the exit previously.

Because of this i include my scripts manually in my login.php file. But wordpress support doesn't allow us to include the script manually in page.
Tell me a way to create a custom page in wordpress admin without having any default content of wordpress.

login.php code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="submitlogin.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Login"/>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's funny, try this one. - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/creating-custom-options-page-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is an option page for certain functionality tied to a WordPress theme or plugin then you need to create an options page and hook into the register_settings() function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

if you're looking to create a page that does something outside of WordPress core then you need to create a menu page and tie it into your plugins hook, like so:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_setup_menu');

function my_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin Page', 'MENU NAME', 'manage_options', 'YOUR PLUGIN SLUG', 'plugin_login_page' );
}

function plugin_login_page(){
    echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
}
```